# libnfc build issue on windows 7 64 bit while executing 'mingw32-make' command

Tags: windows-7, cmake, nfc

While trying to build libnfc-1.6.0-rc1 on 64 bit Windows 7 OS, I am getting undefined reference errors.

I am using below dependencies:

1. Windows 7 64 bit
2. libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0
3. cmake-2.8.10.2-win32-x86
4. tdm64-gcc-4.7.1-3

After successfully generating output from `cmake-gui` command, I get following errors while executing `mingw32-make VERBOSE=1` command:

```
D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1>mingw32-make VERBOSE=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -H"D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1" -B"D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1" --check-build-system CMakeFiles\Makefile.cmake 0
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_start "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles\progress.marks"
mingw32-make -f CMakeFiles\Makefile2 all
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1'
mingw32-make -f libnfc\CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\build.make libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/depend
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_depends "MinGW Makefiles" "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1" "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc" "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1" "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\libnfc" "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\libnfc\CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\DependInfo.cmake" --color=Dependee "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\libnfc\CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\DependInfo.cmake" is newer than depender "D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1/libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/depend.internal".
Dependee "D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1/libnfc/CMakeFiles/CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake" is newer than depender "D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1/libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/depend.internal".
Scanning dependencies of target nfc
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1'
mingw32-make -f libnfc\CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\build.make libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/build
mingw32-make[2]: Entering directory `D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1'
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 1
[  3%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/nfc.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\nfc.c.obj
  -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\nfc.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 2
[  6%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/nfc-device.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\nfc-device.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\nfc-device.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 3
[ 10%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/nfc-emulation.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\nfc-emulation.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\nfc-emulation.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 4
[ 13%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/nfc-internal.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\nfc-internal.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\nfc-internal.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 5
[ 16%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/iso14443-subr.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\iso14443-subr.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\iso14443-subr.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 6
[ 20%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/mirror-subr.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\mirror-subr.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\mirror-subr.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 7
[ 23%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/drivers/acr122.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\drivers\acr122.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\drivers\acr122.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 8
[ 26%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/drivers/pn53x_usb.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\drivers\pn53x_usb.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\drivers\pn53x_usb.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 9
[ 30%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/drivers/arygon.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\drivers\arygon.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\drivers\arygon.c"
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 10
[ 33%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/buses/uart.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\buses\uart.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart.c"
In file included from D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart.c:41:0:
D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart_win32.c: In function 'uart_receive':
D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart_win32.c:159:87: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used [enabled by default]
D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart_win32.c:168:58: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used [enabled by default]
In file included from D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-1.6.0-rc1/contrib/windows.h:31:0,
                 from D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-1.6.0-rc1/config.h:1,
                 from D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart.c:27:
D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-1.6.0-rc1/contrib/win32/err.h:17:13: warning: unused variable 'errx' [-Wunused-variable]
In file included from D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart.c:41:0:
D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart_win32.c: In function 'uart_send':
D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\buses\uart_win32.c:209:87: warning: ISO C99 requires rest arguments to be used [enabled by default]
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_progress_report "D:\libNFC\libnfc-build 1\CMakeFiles" 11
[ 36%] Building C object libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/chips/pn53x.c.obj
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe  -DDRIVER_ACR122_ENABLED -DDRIVER_ARYGON_ENABLED -DDRIVER_PN53X_USB_ENABLED -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -Dnfc_EXPORTS -Du_int16_t=uint16_t -Du_int8_t=uint8_t @CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/includes_C.rsp   -Wall -pedantic -std=c99 -m32 -o CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\chips\pn53x.c.obj   -c "D:\libNFC\libnfc-1.6.0-rc1\libnfc\chips\pn53x.c"
Linking C shared library libnfc.dll
cd /d D:\SOFTWA~1\nfc\libnfc.org\LIBNFC~2\libnfc && "C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\link.txt --verbose=1
"C:\Program Files (x86)\CMake 2.8\bin\cmake.exe" -E remove -f CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a
c:\MinGW64\bin\ar.exe cr CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a @CMakeFiles\nfc.dir\objects1.rsp
c:\MinGW64\bin\gcc.exe   -m32 -shared -o libnfc.dll -Wl,--out-implib,libnfc.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive c:\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib32\libwinscard.a "D:\Software development\usb\libusb\libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0\lib\msvc_x64\libusb.lib" -lwsock32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a(pn53x_usb.c.obj):pn53x_usb.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to `usb_bulk_read'
CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a(pn53x_usb.c.obj):pn53x_usb.c:(.text+0x72): undefined reference to `usb_bulk_write'
:::
CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a(pn53x_usb.c.obj):pn53x_usb.c:(.text+0x9f2): undefined reference to `usb_close'
c:/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.7.1/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: CMakeFiles\nfc.dir/objects.a(pn53x_usb.c.obj): bad relocaddress 0x4c in section `.rdata'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[2]: *** [libnfc/libnfc.dll] Error 1
mingw32-make[2]: Leaving directory `D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1'
mingw32-make[1]: *** [libnfc/CMakeFiles/nfc.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `D:/Software development/nfc/libnfc.org/libnfc-build 1'
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

What could be the problem? Can anyone assist. I am new to NFC development and your timely assistance will be very helpful.

Comment: Looks like 'USB related error'. Check if 'libUSB' installation is proper or not. Is USB library included in system PATH? During configuration in 'cmake-gui', check if correct libUSB library is selected or not.

Comment: @Chandresh. libUSB was not in system path. But I added the below library in **LIBUSB_LIBRARY** property during _cmake-gui_ configuration: **D:\usb\libusb\libusb-win32-bin-1.2.6.0\lib\msvc_x64\libusb.lib**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `..\msvc_x64\libusb.lib`, try to use `..\msvc\libusb.lib` during your cmake-gui configuration and then generate.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. ..\msvc\libusb.lib is the correct lib. `mingw32-make` gave no error.

Comment: Finally. Afer change the **LIBUSB_LIBARIES** to **msvc\libusb.lib** it finally compiled succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for running acr122 and libnfc on windows:

https://huseyincakir.wordpress.com/2014/12/02/libnfc-with-acr122-on-windows-8-1/